# Understanding a Haskell function

Tags: haskell

I am wondering what is the use of `(answers entry)`  in  `totnChars entry = myLoop (answers entry)` . Does it mean that entry must be of type `answers`? But isn't `entry` of type `Entryt`?

```
type Question = [Char]
type Answer = [Char]
type Music = [Char]
data Entryt = MyEntry {
                       questions :: [Question],
                       answers :: [Answer],
                       music :: Music,
                       time :: Float
                      } deriving (Show, Eq) 



totnChars :: Entryt -> Int
totnChars entry = myLoop (answers entry)

myLoop :: [Answer] -> Int
myLoop [] = 0 
myLoop (x:rest) = (nChars x 0) + (myLoop rest)
```

Comment: The type of `answers` is `Entryt -> [Answer]`.

Comment: what do we gain by explicitly writing (answers entry)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`answers` is a getter function that retrieves a given entries answer list, so `totnChars entry = myLoop (answers entry)` defines a function that takes an entry and applies `myLoop` to that entry's answer list.

> Does it mean that entry must be of type answers?

No. The syntax to say that something must be of a given type would be `expression :: Type`, but `answers` isn't a type. Type names always start with capital letters in Haskell. You can introduce a type *variable* named `answers`, but there'd be no point in that. And that's absolutely not what's happening here. `answers entry` is just a plain old function application.

> But isn't entry of type Entryt?

Yes, it is.

Answer (score 3):

`answers` doesn't have type `[Answer]`. It has type `Entryt -> [Answer]`.

“But why?” You may ask.

Each `Entryt` has its own list of answers, which may vary from one `Entryt` to another. Thus, `answers` is a function that takes an `Entryt` and returns its list of answers.